send a folder to a FTP with cli without prompting in UBUNTU
I' using a ci/cd environment on circleci that runs on ubuntu.
I'm trying to send a folder (eventually delete old files) to a FTP address.
I've tried ftp and lftp but I think they use prompt to connect to the FTP.
I would like to avoid bash scripts as it complicated to access cicleci environment variables from there (I guess).
so do you know any command line that would look a bit like this
upload-to-ftp $COMPLETE_URL_WITH_USER_AND_PASSWORD -i $FOLDER_PATH -o $REMOTE_FOLDER_PATH
but if I decide to use bash script I would like to be able to enter input in and non exited program
for the moment here is my bash script and ci pipeline
  - run:
      name: Deploy on FTP
      command: |
          chmod 755 ./.circleci/deploy-to-ftp.sh
          ./.circleci/deploy-to-ftp.sh "$FTP_HOST"

bash:
ftp_host=${FTP_HOST}
lftp
echo $FTP_HOST
echo $(mirror -R /www/ /dist/my-app/browser/)
exit 1


One possible way is to use (file is located in your home directory):
.netrc where you enter structure:
machine <name of the host>
login <username>
password <password for above user>

Then you can exec command:
ftp <name of the host> <<EOF
cd <REMOTE DIR>
lcd <LOCAL DIR>
mput *
bye
EOF

Be aware if you have subdirectories in you <LOCAL DIR> they will not be uploaded, only the files. EOF identifier must be uniq and on the last line there should not be space, tab, etc before the identifier!
If you want to use lftp the command will be something like:
lftp ftp://user:password@hostname -c "lcd <LOCAL DIR>; cd <REMOTE DIR>; mput *; bye"

Bash script which use ftp can se something like:
ftp $1 <<EOF
cd $3
lcd $2
mput *
bye
EOF

You put in .netrc records for every host/user/password you will use.
And you should start the script on this way:
/path/to/script.sh $FTP_HOST /www/ /dist/my-app/browser/

where the variable $FTP_HOST should be only the hostname or IP of the host and should exist in .netrc file!

thank you for your answer I'll do my test and get back to you

ok so I finally tried using a bash script do you want me to reformulate my question any idea How I can enter input from bash with lftp?Thanks in advance.

@JSmith, check my edited answer. If you want entire script you should show in question what did you try so far, what errors you get, where you see problems, etc.

thanks a lot for your concern I've updated my question.I'm a bash newbie

I get open: invalid option -- 'c' with your script

@JSmith, based on the manual lftp must recognize -c

yes I will post the full command line I've used and error message

@JSmith, add script to do the work

Well for some reason the -c option does not work but the '-e' does.I have one last question and this will be finished.How can I quit the process when it's done?It is stuck on connectingeven though the files are uploaded?

I correct I can see on the prompt that files are downloaded but it doesn't exit

@if you talk about lftp will correct the command

This is awesome this works, I wish I could give you more upvots you saved my day.Thanks again

hello it's me, I'm facing an issue where my local directory contains a sub folder and it's not getting copied to the ftp.Any idea with your signle command line why this could happen.Many thanks in advance?
